# Why is the Mersenne twister prefered to using the wichmann hill algorithm to produce pseudo random numbers?

Tags: python, random, mersenne-twister

I read that in version by Python 2.3 https://stackless.readthedocs.io/en/2.7-slp/library/random.html the Mersenne twister replaced the Wichmann-Hill method as default generator. I was wondering if something can elaborate why this one would do that. I understand, that the period is a bigger for the Mersenne twister, but are there other features, that could drive this change?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to says: "[The] period [of WichmannHill] is too short by contemporary standards, and the sequence generated is known to fail some stringent randomness tests." If that explanation is not enough for you, you will have to ask the Python community. Otherwise, it would be speculation to give further reasons on why Mersenne Twister replaced Wichmann-Hill in Python 2.3.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I asked specifically if there is other reasons (should have said other than the ones listed), that could drive this change? So what I was looking for was other reasons: I does not have to be reasons, that the Python team “officially” use. I could ask the Python community but this is more related to RNGs in general. Maybe someone know of reasons, that other programming languages use, when explaining this change.

Comment: Again, it would be speculation to guess what those other reasons are.  For example, I could say that Mersenne Twister was "popular" at the time Python 2.3 was released (in the sense that many applications of the time likewise switched to Mersenne Twister as their PRNG), or that the name "Mersenne _Twister_" was catchy, but this would be my speculation.